# FadeOut callback won't wait to finish

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I have two functions which work together. One to `fadeOut()` a visible article, and one to `fadeIn()` a new one AFTER the previous one is done fading. Somehow, the second function won´t wait for the first to finish. My code is as follows:

```
itemFadeTo: function( item ) {
    
    $( '#item_container article:visible' )
    .stop(true, true)
    .fadeOut( 750, $().itemFadeIn( item ) );

},

itemFadeIn: function( item) {

    $( item )
    .css({ opacity: 0 })
    .show()
    .stop(true, true)
    .animate({ opacity: 1}, 750);

}
```

Called as follows:

```
var new_item= $( 'article#new_item' );

$().itemFadeTo( new_item);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using the built-in fadeIn method?

Comment: There is a possibility the article won't always departure from `opacity:0`. I figured this would give me more 'control'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.fadeOut()` expects a function as its second parameter but you are not passing a function, you are *calling* a function and passing its result as the second parameter:

```
.fadeOut( 750, $().itemFadeIn( item ) );
```

So that means the `$().itemFadeIn( item)` part happens *before* the call to `.fadeOut()`.

Try this instead:

```
.fadeOut( 750, function() { $().itemFadeIn( item ); });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've been trying this before, but somehow it won't call anything then. Even replacing `function() { $().itemFadeIn( item ); }` with `function() { alert('yeehaw!') }` doesn't give a result.

Comment: That's weird. Can you supply a demo at http://jsfiddle.net? Why does your fade out work on a hardcoded selector with `$('#item_container article:visible')` but your call to `$().itemFadeIn()` uses the `item` parameter?

Comment: Because i always want to `fadeOut()` the visible article, the item to  `fadeIn()` differs.